# What's wrong with the pictures vertical spacing?

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats, vertical-spacing

I'm experiencing a vertical spacing glitch with this code, and I'm wondering what am I doing wrong:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

TEST

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
    \quad
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
    \\ % WHAT'S WRONG HERE?
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
    \quad
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
    \caption{Some title and description}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Preview, with the spacing glitch shown in red:

[image]

So what should be a proper spacing separation, instead of `\\`, in the code above?  Of course, I could use something like `\\[0.5in]` or `\\[1ex]` (or other values), but I don't know which spacing command should be best and natural.  I don't want to use a command in my full code, like `\\[1em]` say, to learn later that's not the proper way of doing it.

Ideally, the vertical spacing should be similar to the horizontal `\quad` spacing between both pictures on the same line.

I usually use a subfloat to add some sub-comments below the pictures, but I don't want to do that in this special case.

Comment: I think you just have the interline extra space there, I mean, almost nothing. You are not in a tabular; try using `\par\vspace*{1em}` instead of `\\\` (1em is the quad size, normally)

Comment: Another possibility: use  `\addlinespace`, from `booktabs`.

Comment: @Rmano, it works, but the vertical spacing isn't similar to the quad space between the left and right pictures. How can I get some nice horizontal and vertical spacings?

Comment: @Bernard, what would you suggest to get the same vertical and horizontal spacings, so the four square pictures form a nice square pattern?

Comment: As said in @egreg answer, the problem with my suggestion is that in horizontal you have a space (at the end of your `fbox`) and a `\quad`, and vertically a `\quad` plus the parskip (normally 0pt).

Comment: Usually,  for this kind of things, I use the (sub)floatrow  environment, from the `floatrow` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing strange. LaTeX inserts `\lineskip` glue when two lines are “too near” and the default is 1pt.

You can (locally) set `\lineskip` to what you need for the specific case.

Note that you don't have just `\quad` between images on the same line, because of the unprotected endline. And you need to (locally) set `\fboxsep` just once.

The settings to `\fboxsep` and `\lineskip` will not go past `\end{figure}`.

Oh, and you *don't* want `[H]` here.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

TEST

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{1em}% the same as \quad

\fbox{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}\quad
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\fbox{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}\quad
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\caption{Some title and description}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not [H]? What [htp] is doing?

Comment: @Cham You have a very large `figure` environment and `[H]` will quite likely ruin every attempt at good pagination; with `[htp]` you specify that you want the float “here” or, if not possible, ”top” of a page or, if not possible, in a “page” of floats. In other words, never use `[H]`, ever.

Comment: Your solution appears to be the proper one that I needed.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: egreg, what if I want to increase the spacing, to \setlength{\lineskip}{1.5em} say?  Changing \quad to \hspace*{1.5em} doesn't give exactly the same horizontal spacing as the vertical one.

Comment: @Cham The endline after `\quad` is ignored, but not after `\hspace{1.5em}` and will produce an additional space. Use an appropriate `%` to mask the endline

Comment: Aaah!  That's the kind of stuff I still don't get, with LaTeX.  When to put a weird % or not...  But thanks, I'll try that.  And do I need to put * on the space command?